# Too many values to unpack robotframework ,rest api

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following code . I am trying to get the details of a policy with id 5 .

```
*** Settings ***
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           strings


*** Test Cases ***
Get_Policy_Details
    [Documentation]    This is for getting the list of policies 
    ${auth}=    Create List    admin    admin123
    ${session}=    Create Session    cam_session   https://host132.camb.com:7771    ${auth}    debug=3
    Log    cam_session   
    ${resp}=    Get Request    cam_session    /policies/5
    ${result}=   To JSON      ${resp.content}
    Log    ${result}
```

Following is the response when URL is requested .I am trying to get the values(Firstname,lastname) from the below json .

```
{
  "submittedDT": null,
  "submittedBy": null,
  "id": 5,
  "createdBy": {
    "id": 5,
    "firstName": "Commence",
    "password": null,
    "lastName": "Architect",
    "loginName": "compliancearchitect",
    "organization": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "public"
    },
    "roles": null,
    "emailAddr": null,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "modifiedBy": {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Madhu",
    "password": null,
    "lastName": "RAJU",
    "loginName": "MSRAJU",
    "organization": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "public"
    },
    "roles": null,
    "emailAddr": null,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "complianceScore": null,
  "organization": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "public"
  }
}
```

## report.html

```
TEST CASE: Get_Policy_Details Expand All
    Full Name:  ITOC Tests.Get_Policy_Details
    Documentation:  
    This is for getting the list of policies in ITOC server
    Start / End / Elapsed:  20170313 15:13:08.999 / 20170313 15:13:09.013 / 00:00:00.014
    Status: FAIL (critical)
    Message:    ValueError: too many values to unpack
    KEYWORD: ${auth} = BuiltIn.Create List itocadmin, opsware Expand All
    Documentation:  
    Returns a list containing given items.
    Start / End / Elapsed:  20170313 15:13:09.003 / 20170313 15:13:09.004 / 00:00:00.001
    15:13:09.004    INFO    ${auth} = [u'itocadmin', u'opsware']
    KEYWORD: ${session} = RequestsLibrary.Create Session cam_session, https://host132.camb.com:7771  ${auth}, debug=3 Expand All
    Documentation:  
    Create Session: create a HTTP session to a server
    Start / End / Elapsed:  20170313 15:13:09.005 / 20170313 15:13:09.012 / 00:00:00.007
    15:13:09.006    INFO    Creating Session using : alias=cam_session, url=https://host132.camb.com:7771   headers=[u'admin', u'admin123'],                     cookies=None, auth=None, timeout=None, proxies=None, verify=False,                     debug=3 
    15:13:09.011    FAIL    ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I log JSONs:

```
Get Request and Log
    [Arguments]    ${alias}    ${uri}    ${params}=${EMPTY}
    ${resp}=    Get Request    alias=${alias}    uri=${uri}    params=${params}
    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Log    ${resp.text}
    [Return]    ${resp}
```

So there should be no reason to unpack JSON in your case, just feel free to read from that as you wish:

```
${id} =    Set Variable    ${resp.json().get("id")}
...
```

Comment: And by the way, there are more ways how to read JSONs, see special keywords in BuiltIn library, e.g. Get From Dictionary or Get From List

Comment: Hi Lubos,thanks for the answer but still i am getting error. Can you please let me know how to get token and pass it to get request .`Get Policy With Auth
    ${auth}=  Create List  admin  opre
    Create Session    httpbin    https://hyi01lr0bsaehost1:7771
    ${resp}=  Get Request  alias=httpbin  uri=/policies/5  params=${auth}
    ${id}=  Set Variables  ${resp.json().get('id')}
 Log ${id}`

Comment: Hey, this will not be depending on some general RF solution but up to your product. Usually you have to log in first and there will be some token value in the login response. Get it from that, compose new request (you might need to add in into some cookie) and retain it for each request.

Comment: Thanks Lubos, I got the required output `Get Policy With Auth
    @{auth}=  Create List  admin  opre
    Create Session    httpbin    https://hyi01lr032.ind.ca.com:7771/  auth=@{auth}
    ${resp}=  Get Request  httpbin  uri=/policies/5
    Log  ${resp.status_code}
 Log  ${resp.json()['name']}
 Log  ${resp.json()['createdBy']['firstName']}
 Log  ${resp.json()['createdBy']['organization']['name']}
 Log  ${resp.json()['modifiedBy']['firstName']}
`